# How does 'for' evaluate to true or false in an all() function?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, boolean

I am working through project Euler and have made it to [problem #7](https://projecteuler.net/problem=7). I worked out a solution with the help of a video I found online, but there is one line of code that I don't understand. Here is the problem and my solution.

```
"""By listing the first six prime numbers: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, and 13, we can see that the 6th prime is 13.
What is the 10 001st prime number?"""

primes = []
x = 2

while(len(primes)) < 10001:
    if all(x % prime for prime in primes):
        primes.append(x)
    x += 1

print(primes[-1])
```

I'm confused about the all() function. I know that `x % prime` will evaluate to true if the remainder is not zero, but what exactly is the function doing with the for statement? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `all` will look for all True values inside the generator expression

Comment: Google list comprehension to learn more about that syntax, then generator expression

Comment: This is covered quite well in the many sites that provide base documentation, and those the give working examples.  What did you not understand from your reserach?

Comment: Perhaps looking at the equivalent python code will help https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all Note in the for-loop, the first time you encounter an element that evaluates to false, you get false, otherwise true. In plain Engish - all values of an interable must be true to make all() return true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is using [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python). It is taking each of the numbers from the array `primes` and defining them as `prime`. It then uses that to evaluate `x % prime`.

Put into a for loop `x % prime for prime in primes` would look like:

```
for prime in primes:
    return x % prime
```

Next, `all()` checks if all of them equate truthy (or true). So if one of the returns from the for loop mentioned above is false, the entire if statement returns false.